# Can i configure Phantomjs to run in Internet Explorer than Firefox?

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, phantomjs

How can I Configure PhantomJS to run in Internet Explorer than default firefox

Comment: PhantomJS is a complete browser. It doesn't run in Firefox or IE or Chrome. It also can't emulate Firefox or IE or Chrome.

Comment: Thanks Artjom, I was able to take screenshots while phantom was running and the UI is completely the same as in firefox but my problem is i cant seem to win in clicking buttons and links while using Phantom but after commenting Phantom code out back to webdriver my end to end script runs perfectly. Is there a solution you might suggest to Phantom not picking up some of the elements?

Comment: You need to provide a description of your problem along with the minimal code that is necessary to reproduce your issue. Normally I would say that you need to [edit] your question to include those things, but your question already has an answer. Changing the question would confuse future readers if they see that the answer doesn't answer the (changed) question. You should ask a new and detailed question.

Comment: Thanks Artjom, i shall try that.

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple to understand, you can compare PhantomJS to firefox or IE, but with no interface... so what you just said is basically - "Can I run Firefox in IE?"...

Regarding tests running headless using phantomJS vs browser, you might encounter differences...

Top 2 differences I encountered are:

1:. Headless tests are too fast and you need loads of waiters or even sleeps (bad practice) to slow it down so elements are clickable/visible at the time your step runs...
2:. Overlapping elements which is resolved by element.trigger('click') rather than element.click

Comment: Been trying more sleeps but they dont seem to work for my script, i end up sleeping for too long. will check the second option, element trigger. Thanks